# How to use the tr REPEAT modifier to replace a character with a repeated character?

Tags: shell, text-processing, tr

I'm using the `tr` command to replace newlines with tabs from an output of another command, and I want to have multiple tabs to better align the output to a columnar format.

I see that `tr` has a `[CHAR*REPEAT]` option, where `REPEAT` could be a decimal or octal value, but I can't get it to work, e.g. the following simple line:

```
echo "1234" | tr ['2'] ['x'*3]
```

gives:

```
1x34
```

while I'm expecting:

```
1xxx34
```

What's the correct syntax to use?

Comment: Funny how you'd quote characters that don't need quoting (like `2` or `x`), and didn't those that do (`[`, `]`, `*`). `tr '[2]abc' '[x*3][y*3]` translate `[`, `2` and `]` to `x` and `a`, `b`, `c` to `y`, it's another way to write `tr '[2]abc' xxxyyy`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's just one of a dozen other attempts at getting the expected result, thinking that the problem was in the way I expresses that CHAR man pages talks about :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid you are misunderstanding the meaning of the "repeat" option.

`tr`, as you correctly infer, is used to translate character sets. You call it with option

```
tr set1 set2
```

The idea is that both sets can contain multiple characters, i.e. you can say

```
tr 'abc' 'def'
```

and it will replace every `a` with a `d`, every `b` with an `e`, and every `c` with an `f`. Now, sometimes you want to replace multiple "input" characters with the same "output" character, say

```
tr 'abcdefghij' 'xxxxxxxxyz'
```

This will replace `a` to `h` with  `x`, `i` with `y`, and `j` with `z`. The "repeat" function is meant to make writing this less cumbersome, so that you can instead write

```
tr 'abcdefghij' '[x*8]yz'
```

as shorthand. Unfortunately, that means it is not designed for what you intend to do.

**Instead**, you can try `sed`

```
$ echo "1234" | sed 's/2/xxx/g'
1xxx34
```

This will substitute (`s`) all occurences (the trailing `g`) of `2` with `xxx`. Since `sed` is far more powerful than that (have a look at the questions tagged as [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for an overview of what is possible), it may be a good idea to have a look into anyway.

Comment: Ha! `[CHAR*REPEAT] REPEAT copies of CHAR, REPEAT octal if starting with 0` may I be forgiven for the misunderstanding? :-) Thanks, I'll definitely move to sed.

Comment: `sed` also has a `y/abc/xyz/` to do `tr`'s job though doesn't support the `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` and co. Some have `\U`/`\u` as a non-standard extension though.

Comment: @watery I will certainly excuse you; had sufficient cases of misunderstandings myself ;). But yes, it would really seem like the best option to use `sed` for your use case ...

Comment: ... or perhaps perl, which **does** have a repeat (string multiplication) operator (confusingly - for this example - the operator is `x`): `echo "1234" | perl -pe 's/2/x x 3/ge'`